# Show that $\sin(kx)$ and $\cos(kx)$ are polynomial uniform limits

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, uniform-continuity

Since linear combinations of $\sin(kx)$ and $\cos(kx)$ for $n\in \mathbb{N}$ form a dense subset in $(C([-\pi , \pi]), \|\cdot \|_{\infty})$. We want to show that $\sin(kx)$ and $\cos(kx)$ are polynomial uniform limits in term of $x$ on the interval $[-\pi , \pi]$, and conclude that the set of polynomial functions is dense in $(C([-\pi , \pi]), \|\cdot \|_{\infty})$.

I am not sure how to prove this. I have proven that for $A, B\subset (X, d)$, if $B\subset \overline{A}$ and $B$ is $d$-dense in $X$ then $A$ is $d$-dense in $X$. I think this should help me but I don't know how to apply this my problem. If anyone has an idea, I would appreciate it.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by polynomial uniform limits in term of $x$?

Comment: Also, if $\overline A\subset B$ and $B$ is $d$-dense in $X$ then it does not need to follow that $A$ is $d$-dense in $X$. Consider $X=B=[0,1]$, $A=\{0.5\}$.

Comment: I mean $\sin(kx)$ and $\cos(kx)$ are uniform limits of polynomial. Sorry, I wanted to say $B\subset \overline{A}$.

Comment: Power series are known to converge uniformly on compact subsets of their disc of convergence. So just use the power series expansion of the trigonometric functions.

Answer (score 1):

It is well-known that $\sin y$ and $\cos y$ can be represented by their Taylor series

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n\frac{y^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!} \text{ and } \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n\frac{y^{2n}}{(2n)!} .$$

Both series have radius of convergence $= \infty$, thus convergence is uniform on each compact subset of $\mathbb R$, especially on $[-k\pi,k\pi]$. This means that for each $\epsilon > 0$ we find $M$ such that for all $m \ge N$ and all $y \in [-k\pi,k\pi]$
$$\left\lvert \sin(y) - \sum_{n=0}^m (-1)^n\frac{y^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!} \right\rvert < \epsilon \text{ and } \left\lvert \cos(y) - \sum_{n=0}^m (-1)^n\frac{y^{2n}}{(2n)!} \right\rvert < \epsilon .$$
Substituting $y = kx$ shows that for each $\epsilon > 0$ we find $M$ such that for all $m \ge N$ and all $x \in [-\pi,\pi]$
$$\left\lvert \sin(kx) - \sum_{n=0}^m (-1)^nk^{2n+1}\frac{x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!} \right\rvert < \epsilon \text{ and } \left\lvert \cos(kx) - \sum_{n=0}^m (-1)^nk^{2n}\frac{x^{2n}}{(2n)!} \right\rvert < \epsilon .$$
This shows that the functions $\sin(kx)$ and $\cos(kx)$ are uniform limits of polynomial functions.

In other words, if $P([-\pi,\pi])$ denotes the set of all polynomial functions, then for each $k \in \mathbb N$
$$\sin(kx), \cos(kx) \in \overline{P([-\pi,\pi])} , \tag{1}$$
where $\overline{\phantom{X}}$ denotes closure in $(C([-\pi , \pi]), \|\cdot \|_{\infty})$.

If $T([-\pi,\pi])$ denotes the set of all linear combinations of elements in $\{ \sin(kx) \mid k \in \mathbb N \} \cup \{ \cos(kx) \mid k \in \mathbb N \} $, then of course
$$T([-\pi,\pi]) \subset \overline{P([-\pi,\pi])} . \tag{2}$$
Since $\overline{P([-\pi,\pi])} $ is closed, we have
$$\overline{T([-\pi,\pi])} \subset \overline{P([-\pi,\pi])} . \tag{3}$$
But we know that $\overline{T([-\pi,\pi])} = C([-\pi,\pi])$, thus
$$\overline{P([-\pi,\pi])} =  C([-\pi,\pi]) .$$.

Comment: This is only for the uniform limits ? It does not show that the set of polynomial functions is dense in (C([−π,π]),∥⋅∥∞) ?

Comment: @groi See my edit.

Answer (score 0):

**Hints**:

Use the Taylor expansion of $\sin(kx)$ and $\cos(kx)$ to find polynomials that approximate
these functions.
Then use [some of the formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem#Explicit_formulas_for_the_remainder) for the remainder.
Then you can estimate the reminder for a bound that does not depend on $x$.
This bound should then go to $0$ as you increase the degree of the polynomial.

As for the overall question: For a given continuous function,
first approximate it using a linear combination of $\sin(kx),\cos(kx)$,
then use polynomials to approximate this linear combination.
Using a triangle inequality should yield the result.

Comment: I don't see which formula of the remainder I should use and how to estimate it for a bound that does not depend on $x$. Also, would it be possible to use Fejer theorem ?

Comment: Which formulas of the remainder have you tried? There are multiple forms, and you might have to try some until you find one that is easier to handle.

You can try Fejer if you want, but I am not sure how successful it will be.

Comment: I thought using the mean-value forms of the remainder.